# Send email if old unread mail exist

Tags: vba, outlook, runtime-error

I'm trying to send myself an email if there are any unread emails over 15 minutes old.

The code, when I manually run from within Outlook, sends the mail but I get a

> Run time error '-2147221238' (8004010a)

I can't get it to run from a rule or stand alone with task schedule probably due to the above error.

```
Sub checkForUnreadMails()

    Dim objFolder, objNamespace
    'get running outlook application or open outlook
    Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If objOutlook Is Nothing Then
        Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If

    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    strFilter = "[received] <= '" & Format(DateAdd("n", -15, Now()), "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
    Debug.Print strFilter
    Set inboxItems = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items.Restrict(strFilter)
    strFilter = "[Unread] = True"
    Set unreadItems = inboxItems.Restrict(strFilter)

    For Each itm In unreadItems
        With objMsg
            .To = "email@email.com"
            .Subject = "outlookrule There are unread emails over 15 minutes old in Vision ATM mailbox"
            .Categories = "T"
            .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain ' send plain text message
            .Importance = olImportanceHigh
            .Sensitivity = olConfidential
            .Send
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: On which line is the error? Take a minute to take the tour : http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: shows the error on line 22 - the email address

Answer (score 5):

The error code is MAPI_E_OBJECT_DELETED. Your code does no make much sense - you create objMsg once, but attempt to send it multiple time (which you can't) for each unread item.

Why are you sending an email multiple times for each unread email? You do not actually retrieve any information from that email. Either simply check if there are matching emails (`unreadItems.Count > 0`) and send an email once, or create a new message (`Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)`) on each iteration of the loop and include some particular email details.

```
Sub checkForUnreadMails()

    Dim objFolder, objNamespace
    'get running outlook application or open outlook
    Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If objOutlook Is Nothing Then
        Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If

Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

strFilter = "[received] <= '" & Format(DateAdd("n", -15, Now()), "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
Debug.Print strFilter
Set inboxItems = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items.Restrict(strFilter)
strFilter = "[Unread] = True"
Set unreadItems = inboxItems.Restrict(strFilter)
if unreadItems.Count > 0 Then 
  Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  With objMsg
                .To = "email@email.com"
                .Subject = "outlookrule There are unread emails over 15 minutes old in Vision ATM mailbox"
                .Categories = "T"
                .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain ' send plain text message
                .Importance = olImportanceHigh
                .Sensitivity = olConfidential
                .Send
        End With
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I dont want to send an email multiple times just want to check the box and if there are unread emails over 15 minutes old then send me an email once.

Comment: my problem is im new to VBA coding and dont really understand

Comment: Thank you  - This works perfectly - would i be able to use this as a .vba file outside of outlook so i can use task schedule to repeat the action at certain times ?

Comment: Yes, VBS file will work,  just replace constants defined in the Outlook type library with their numerical values - olFolderInbox with 6, olMailItem 0, olFormatPlain 1, olImportanceHigh 2, olConfidential 3. Keep in mind that Task Scheduler runs as a service, and OOM cannot be used in a service.

Answer (score 1):

Just launch `StartTimer` once you opened Outlook, 
and it'll run `checkForUnreadMails` every 15 minutes until you close Outlook!

```
Option Explicit

Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunIntervalSeconds = 900 ' 15 minutes
Public Const cRunWhat = "checkForUnreadMails"  ' the name of the procedure to run

Sub StartTimer()
    RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, cRunIntervalSeconds)
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, _
        Schedule:=True
End Sub



Sub checkForUnreadMails()
    Dim objFolder, objNamespace
    Dim areUnread As Boolean
    areUnread = False

    '''get running outlook application or open outlook
    Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If objOutlook Is Nothing Then Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    strFilter = "[received] <= '" & Format(DateAdd("n", -15, Now()), "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
    'Debug.Print strFilter
    Set inboxItems = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items.Restrict(strFilter)
    strFilter = "[Unread] = True"
    Set unreadItems = inboxItems.Restrict(strFilter)

    For Each itm In unreadItems
        If itm.Subject <> vbNullString Then
            areUnread = True
            Exit For
        Else
        End If
    Next itm

    If areUnread Then
        With objMsg
            .to = "email@email.com"
            .Subject = "outlookrule There are unread emails over 15 minutes old in Vision ATM mailbox"
            .Categories = "T"
            .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
            '''send plain text message
            .Importance = olImportanceHigh
            .Sensitivity = olConfidential
            .Send
        End With 'objMsg
    End If

    StartTimer
End Sub
```

Use this to stop the timer, when you want to keep Outlook open and not run the sricpt every 15 minutes

```
Sub StopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, _
        Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly - would i be able to use this as a .vba file outside of outlook so i can use task schedule to repeat the action at certain times ?

Comment: @user3165962 : Take a look at the edit, I included the `OnTime` method to run the check every 15 minutes!